# Github multiple machine with single user

Tags: git, github

I am trying to access a github repository from my desktop and laptop with the same user. Could it be possible, if yes then how?

I am thankful to you for your cooperation and time.

Yours,

Comment: Can you elaborate a little and say what you mean by "access a github repository"? Just cloning it? Are you facing problems? If so, what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a key pair on each machine to push to Github, and you can add as much ssh keys as you wish via https://github.com/account/ssh page.

Comment: +1 for "a separate key on each machine". Do not copy private keys around.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are to ways :

**First solution**

Yes you can shared your ssh public/private keys to access to your github repository. By default, your keys are situated in the `~/.ssh/` folder (id_rsa is your private key, id_rsa.pub is your public key).

---

**Second solution (preferable)**

However, another solution is to create a new pair of keys and put the new public key in [your github account](https://github.com/account/ssh).

To do that, you can use the `ssh-keygen` command. After that, you put the new `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on your github account as I said above. Don't forget to tape a passphrase when you use the `ssh-keygen` command to have more security.